# filtering CSV file using function parameters

Tags: python, csv, filter

So I am writing a function to filter a csv file according to the function parameters and then find the average for a column after the filtering. I'm only allowed to use import csv (no pandas) and can't use lambda or any other python "advanced" shortcuts. I feel like I can get the average part easy but I am having trouble with filtering it according to the parameters and the constraints I have mentioned. I would usually go about this by using pandas which makes this process easier but I can't.

This is my code:

```
def calc_avg(self, specific, filter, logic, threshold):
        
        with open(self.load_data, 'r') as avg_file:
            for row in csv.DictReader(avg_file, delimiter= ','):
                specific = row[specific]
                filter = int(row[filter])
                logic = logic
                threshold = 0
                
                if logic == 'lt':
                    filter < threshold
                    
                elif logic == 'gt':
                    filter > threshold
                    
                elif logic == 'lte':
                    filter <= threshold
                    
                elif logic == 'gte':
                    filter >= threshold
```

it should work with this command

```
print(csv_data.calc_avg("Length_of_stay", filter="SOFA", logic="lt", threshold="15"))
```

This is the format of the code, and column headers.
Sample Data:

```
RecordID SAPS-I SOFA    Length_of_stay  
132539    6      1         5    
132540    16     8         8    
132541    21     11       19    
132545    17     2         4    
132547    14     11        6    
132548    14     4         9    
132551    19     8         6    
132554    11     0        17
```

Comment: Welcome VS, can you provide sample data?

Comment: You use `filter` twice: as a parameter and as an integer... is `SOFA` supposed to be the column name?

Comment: hello, I added in the sample data. I have to use the filter as a parameter and I changed it to an integer because I got an error that said I can't compare two different types. I'm confused because the number is given as a string too  for threshold instead of a number.

Comment: Not related to the problem, but why do you do `threshold = 0` instead of using the parameter supplied by the caller?

Comment: what are the intended roles of `specific` and `filter`? and what is the expected output from your sample data?

Comment: @RichieV ```specific``` is for the specific column will be averaged and ```filter``` is the column that will be filtered. That output should be the average of the specific column based off the filter that is assigned. So I should be getting average of length of stay for SOFA < 15.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update

This option evaluates `logic` once and returns a function `compare` that can be used while iterating rows. It is faster when data has many rows.

```py
# written as a function because you don't share the definition of load_data
# but the main idea can be translated to a class
def calc_avg(self, specific, filter, logic, threshold):
    if isinstance(threshold, str):
        threshold = float(threshold)
    
    def lt(a, b): return a < b
    def gt(a, b): return a > b
    def lte(a, b): return a <= b
    def gte(a, b): return a >= b
    
    if logic == 'lt': compare = lt
    elif logic == 'gt': compare = gt
    elif logic == 'lte': compare = lte
    elif logic == 'gte': compare = gte
    
    with io.StringIO(self) as avg_file: # change to open an actual file
        running_sum = running_count = 0
        for row in csv.DictReader(avg_file, delimiter=','):
            if compare(int(row[filter]), threshold):
                running_sum += int(row[specific])
                # or float(row[specific])
                running_count += 1
        
    if running_count == 0:
        # no even one row passed the filter
        return 0
    else:
        return running_sum / running_count

print(calc_avg(data, 'Length_of_stay', 'SOFA', 'lt', '15'))
print(calc_avg(data, 'Length_of_stay', 'SOFA', 'lt', '2'))
print(calc_avg(data, 'Length_of_stay', 'SOFA', 'lt', '0'))
```

Output

```
9.25
11.0
0
```

---

Initial answer

In order to filter the rows you have to do something with the comparison once you identify which type of inequality you are supposed to use. The code here stores that in a boolean `include`.

Then you can have two variables: `running_sum` and `running_count` which later should be divided to return the average.

```py
import io
import csv

# written as a function because you don't share the definition of load_data
# but the main idea can be translated to a class
def calc_avg(self, specific, filter, logic, threshold):
    if isinstance(threshold, str):
        threshold = float(threshold)

    with io.StringIO(self) as avg_file: # change to open an actual file
        running_sum = running_count = 0
        for row in csv.DictReader(avg_file, delimiter=','):
            # your code has: filter = int(row[filter])
            value = int(row[filter]) # avoid overwriting parameters
            
            if logic == 'lt' and value < threshold:
                include = True
            elif logic == 'gt' and value > threshold:
                include = True
            elif logic == 'lte' and value <= threshold: # should it be 'le'
                include = True
            elif logic == 'gte' and value >= threshold: # should it be 'ge'
                include = True
            # or import ast and consider all cases in one line
            # if ast.literal_eval(f'{value}{logic}{treshold}'):
                # include = True
            else:
                include = False
            
            if include:
                running_sum += int(row[specific])
                # or float(row[specific])
                running_count += 1
        
        return running_sum / running_count
    

data = """RecordID,SAPS-I,SOFA,Length_of_stay
132539,6,1,5
132540,16,8,8
132541,21,11,19
132545,17,2,4
132547,14,11,6
132548,14,4,9
132551,19,8,6
132554,11,0,17"""


print(calc_avg(data, 'Length_of_stay', 'SOFA', 'lt', '15'))
print(calc_avg(data, 'Length_of_stay', 'SOFA', 'lt', '2'))
```

Output

```
9.25
11.0
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I should've shared load_data but yes that is a function too and can be substituted. I'll check on it later today to see if it runs and keep you updated!

Answer (score 0):

You're not doing anything with the result of your comparisons. You need to use them in the `if` statements to include the specific value in your average calculation.

```
def calc_avg(self, specific, filter, logic, threshold):
    with open(self.load_data, 'r') as avg_file:
        values = []
        for row in csv.DictReader(avg_file, delimiter= ','):
            specific = row[specific]
            filter = int(row[filter])
            threshold = 0

            if logic == 'lt' and filter < threshold:
                values.append(specific)
            elif logic == 'gt' and filter > threshold:
                values.append(specific)
            elif logic == 'lte' and filter <= threshold:
                values.append(specific)
            elif logic == 'gte' and filter >= threshold:
                values.append(specific)
        if len(values) > 0:
            return sum(values) / len(values)
        else:
            return 0
```

Comment: I get a key error for the code. I think it might be because I am using Dictreader but I don't really know how to make sure I can filter everything by the headers if I don't do it this way.

Comment: If you're getting `KeyError` then you're giving an incorrect column name in the function arguments.

Comment: Make sure you get the upper and lower case correct.